# Area boundary coordinates using Google Maps API for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, maps, mkmapview

Sorry, my english was bad.

Is it possible to get area boundary lat/longs to draw area polygon using Google maps API.

Using this I need to draw overlay on MKMapview.

Required any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to get lat/lng by using [`Google Places API`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details), the Google Places API for iOS provides your app with rich information about places, including the place's name and address, the geographical location specified as latitude/longitude coordinates. Aside from that, you can use `overlays` to layer content over a wide portion of the map. An overlay object is any object that conforms to the [MKOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKOverlay) protocol. An overlay object is a data object that contains the points needed to specify the shape and size of the overlay and its location on the map. Overlays can represent shapes such as circles, rectangles, multi-segment lines, and simple or complex polygons. You can also define your own custom overlays to represent other shapes.

*Note:*

> In iOS 7 and OS X v10.9 and later, the presentation of an overlay is handled by an `overlay renderer` object, which is an instance of the [MKOverlayRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayRenderer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayRenderer) class. The job of the renderer is to draw the overlay’s content onto the screen when asked to do so by the map view. For example, if you have a simple overlay that represents a bus route, you could use a polyline renderer to draw the line segments that trace the route of the bus. You could also define a custom renderer that draws both the bus route and icons at the location of each bus stop. When specifying [overlays](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/overlays), you can add them to specific levels of the map, which allows them to be rendered above or below other types of map content. Prior to iOS 7, overlays a
>   Show less
>   Dexter Datul
>   Dexter Datul
>   1:07 PM Today
>   re drawn on onscreen using overlay views, which are instances of the [MKOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayView) class.

When configuring your map interface, you can add overlay objects at any time. The map view uses the data in each overlay object to determine when the corresponding overlay view needs to appear onscreen. When an overlay moves onscreen, the map view asks its delegate to create a corresponding overlay renderer.

Comment: Thanks datul for responding. I implemented this part and to display a polygon we need to get coordinates. Can we get those using google API? Stuck up with data part and implementation is done.

Comment: @Android Enthusiast i am also looking for same , did you able to found same ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Google API :

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)getLatLongFromAddress:(NSString*) addressStr
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    if (result)
    {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil])
        {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil])
            {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;
}
```

Using Geocoder :

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        if(!error)
        {
            if([placemarks count] > 0)
            {
                CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            }
        }
   }];
```

Comment: Using this we can get a location but not the area. For example if we select "Dallas" that was available in texas. Can we get "Texas" boundaries(series of coordinates) to draw a polygon. thanks for responding

Comment: Hey , Can please help me how have to done this I need same. thanks in advance.